# I need to search with multi variable and sort

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064, mysql-error-1054

I can search multiple value with mysql.
I need to implement SORT BY on it

This is my coding which is working perfect

```
   $conditions = array();
if ($key) {
  $conditions[] = 'job_title LIKE "%'.$key.'%"';
}
if ($category) {
  $conditions[] = 'job_category = "'.$category.'"';
}
if ($location) {
  $conditions[] = 'job_location = "'.$location.'"';
}
if ($country) {
  $conditions[] = 'job_country = "'.$country.'"';
}
if ($salary) {
  $conditions[] = 'job_salary >= "'.$salary.'"';
}


$sqlStatement = 'SELECT * FROM jobs JOIN job_category ON  jobs.job_category=job_category.category_id  '.implode(' AND ', $conditions);
```

When I apply SORT BY
like this

```
if ($sort) 
{
$conditions[] = 'ORDER BY "'.$sort.'"';
$sqlStatement = 'SELECT * FROM jobs JOIN job_category ON  jobs.job_category=job_category.category_id  '.implode(' AND ', $conditions);
}
else
{
$sqlStatement = 'SELECT * FROM jobs JOIN job_category ON  jobs.job_category=job_category.category_id  '.implode(' AND ', $conditions);
}
```

result is

> Blockquote
>   SELECT * FROM jobs JOIN job_category ON jobs.job_category=job_category.category_id job_location = "Manjeri" AND ORDER BY "job_salary"
>   Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/work/mobjob/test.php on line 41

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you shouldn't implode your order by as a condition.. it's not one..

just append it onto the end like so:

```
$sqlStatement = 'SELECT * FROM jobs JOIN job_category ON  jobs.job_category=job_category.category_id  ';

if( sizeof($conditions)) {
    $sqlStatement .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $conditions);
}



if($sort) {
    $sqlStatement .= ' ORDER BY "'.$sort.'"';
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for your response 

this is the result when I'm coding that way :( 

SELECT * FROM jobs JOIN job_category ON jobs.job_category=job_category.category_id 'WHERE' ORDER BY job_salary

Comment: sorry, I just copy/pasted you bad code into my answer. Editing answer to help